# Why isn't my C shell outputting anything?

Tags: c, shell, fork, execvp

Working on a project for a class. We're supposed to write a C shell. I've found a bunch of good examples, but for the life of me, I can't get my version to generate any output.

It keeps printing the prompt, but nothing else.

I've followed along with some examples near-verbatim trying to fix this, but still nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <stdbool.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>



/******************************************

  @brief Fork a child to execute the command using execvp. The parent should wait for the child to terminate

  @param args Null terminated list of arguments (including program).

  @return returns 1, to continue execution and 0 to terminate the MyShell prompt.

******************************************/

int execute(char **args)

{

    pid_t  pid;
        int status;

        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) 
        {     
              printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
              exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) 
        {          
          if (execvp(*args, args) < 0) {     
               printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
               exit(1);
          }
        }
        else 
        {                                  
          while (wait(&status) != pid)       
               ;
        }
        
        return 0;

}





/******************************************

  @brief gets the input from the prompt and splits it into tokens. Prepares the arguments for execvp

  @return returns char** args to be used by execvp

******************************************/

char** parse(void)

{

    //Get the string and store it. Remove newline.  

    char strIn[255];

    printf("MyShell>");

    fgets(strIn, sizeof(strIn), stdin); 

    strIn[strlen(strIn)-1]='\0';

    

    //Array, token, counters. 

    char *args[20]; 

    char *tok; 

    int i = 0;

    int count = 0;

    

    //Allocate array. 

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)

    {

        args[i] = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

    }

    

    //Fill in args[0]

    tok = strtok(strIn, " ");

    strcpy(args[count++], tok);

    

    //Fill in array with tokens. 

    while (tok != NULL)

    {

        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");

        

        if (tok == NULL)

            break;

            

        strcpy(args[count++], tok);

    }

    

    //Null terminate.

    args[count] = NULL;

        

    return args; 

}





/******************************************

   @brief Main function should run infinitely until terminated manually using CTRL+C or typing in the exit command

   It should call the parse() and execute() functions

   @param argc Argument count.

   @param argv Argument vector.

   @return status code

******************************************/

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{

    bool run = true; 

    

    while(run)

    {

        char** argArr = parse(); 

        execute(argArr);


        }

        

    return 0;

}
```

The output, regardless of what I do, is:

```
MyShell>
MyShell>
MyShell>
```

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: [`fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) tends to undefined-behavior.

Comment: Just removed that, forgot I had it in there. Also took out a badly-written print statement in execute. I don't think either had much of an effect on the problem though.

Comment: `parse` returns a pointer to the local array `args` whose lifetime ends when `parse` returns.  [Look at your compiler warnings!](https://godbolt.org/z/q91GGx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse()` returns a pointer to the local array `args`.  Since the lifetime of `args` ends when `parse()` returns, any attempt to use the return value of `parse()` is undefined behavior.  You should allocate that array with `malloc()` instead (and free it later!).

What happens in my test is that the compiler notices that the return value of `parse()` can't legally be used ([and it gives a warning!! which you should read and pay attention to!!](https://godbolt.org/z/q91GGx)), so it just returns `NULL` instead.  When the child dereferences this pointer as `*args` to get the first argument for `execvp`, it segfaults and dies without calling `execvp()`.  You could detect this if you checked the `status` returned by `wait()`, but you don't.  So it just looks as if the child didn't do anything.

Oh, bonus bug: when end-of-file occurs on `stdin` (e.g. if you hit Ctrl-D), the string returned by `fgets()` will be empty and `strIn[strlen(strIn)-1]='\0';` will store a null byte out of bounds.  You need to test the return value of `fgets()`.

Comment: Well, this definitely helps. I think it's a bad case of spaghetti code after trying one too many tweaks to get a bunch of different things I'm not super familiar with working properly.

Comment: That strategy may work in some languages, but in C, as you are finding, it's overwhelmingly likely to result in bullets in your feet.

Comment: Update: that did it. Thanks for the fast fix. I'm going to go clean my code up and make sure to dealloc the offending array later. Have a good one!